# Solr BlockJoinQuery returns false positives

Tags: solr, solrcloud

We are trying to query indexed nested child documents in Solr but when we query for example to return a parent of a child where `event_id: order-1` the result has a parent which has a child with `event_id: order-5`.

We did setup a fresh Solr using Solr's example data and when querying that, the returned results were correct. Idea was that maybe there is something in `solrconfig.xml` but after removing or setting things back to default, the results were still incorrect.

Currently we're working on checking `schema.xml` to see if we can correct results that way.

Our current `solrconfig.xml`

```
<config>
  <luceneMatchVersion>8.11.2</luceneMatchVersion>
  <directoryFactory name="DirectoryFactory" class="${solr.directoryFactory:solr.StandardDirectoryFactory}" />
  <schemaFactory class="ClassicIndexSchemaFactory"/>

  <indexConfig>
    <lockType>single</lockType>

    <ramBufferSizeMB>256</ramBufferSizeMB>

    <mergePolicyFactory class="org.apache.solr.index.SortingMergePolicyFactory">
      <str name="sort">id asc</str>
      <str name="wrapped.prefix">inner</str>
      <str name="inner.class">org.apache.solr.index.TieredMergePolicyFactory</str>
      <int name="inner.maxMergeAtOnce">10</int>
      <int name="inner.segmentsPerTier">10</int>
      <int name="inner.deletesPctAllowed">20</int>
    </mergePolicyFactory>

  </indexConfig>

  <updateHandler class="solr.DirectUpdateHandler2">

    <autoCommit>
      <maxDocs>1000000</maxDocs>
      <maxSize>2g</maxSize>
      <openSearcher>false</openSearcher>
    </autoCommit>

    <updateLog>
      <str name="dir">${solr.data.dir:}</str>
    </updateLog>
  </updateHandler>
  <query>
    <maxBooleanClauses>102400</maxBooleanClauses>

    <filterCache class="solr.CaffeineCache" maxRamMB="750" initialSize="0" autowarmCount="0" />
    <queryResultCache class="solr.CaffeineCache" size="512" initialSize="0" autowarmCount="0" />
    <fieldValueCache class="solr.CaffeineCache" size="1" initialSize="0" autowarmCount="0" />
    <enableLazyFieldLoading>true</enableLazyFieldLoading>
    <queryResultWindowSize>0</queryResultWindowSize>
    <queryResultMaxDocsCached>200</queryResultMaxDocsCached>
    <useColdSearcher>false</useColdSearcher>
    <maxWarmingSearchers>2</maxWarmingSearchers>
  </query>

  <requestDispatcher handleSelect="false">
    <requestParsers enableRemoteStreaming="true" multipartUploadLimitInKB="2048000" />
    <httpCaching never304="true" />
  </requestDispatcher>
  <requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
      <int name="rows">10</int>
      <str name="df">text</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>

  <requestHandler name="/update" class="solr.UpdateRequestHandler"></requestHandler>
</config>
```

Our current `schema.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<schema name="default-config" version="1.6">
    <fieldType name="_nest_path_" class="solr.NestPathField" />

    <!-- The StrField type is not analyzed, but indexed/stored verbatim. -->
    <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" docValues="true" />
    <fieldType name="strings" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" multiValued="true" docValues="true" />

    <!-- boolean type: "true" or "false" -->
    <fieldType name="boolean" class="solr.BoolField" sortMissingLast="true" />
    <fieldType name="booleans" class="solr.BoolField" sortMissingLast="true" multiValued="true" />

    <!-- Numeric field types that index values using KD-trees. Point fields don't support FieldCache, so they must have docValues="true" 
        if needed for sorting, faceting, functions, etc. -->
    <fieldType name="pint" class="solr.IntPointField" docValues="true" />
    <fieldType name="pfloat" class="solr.FloatPointField" docValues="true" />
    <fieldType name="plong" class="solr.LongPointField" docValues="true" />
    <fieldType name="pdouble" class="solr.DoublePointField" docValues="true" />

    <fieldType name="pints" class="solr.IntPointField" docValues="true" multiValued="true" />
    <fieldType name="pfloats" class="solr.FloatPointField" docValues="true" multiValued="true" />
    <fieldType name="plongs" class="solr.LongPointField" docValues="true" multiValued="true" />
    <fieldType name="pdoubles" class="solr.DoublePointField" docValues="true" multiValued="true" />

    <!-- KD-tree versions of date fields -->
    <fieldType name="pdate" class="solr.DatePointField" docValues="true" />
    <fieldType name="pdates" class="solr.DatePointField" docValues="true" multiValued="true" />

    <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>

    <!-- Solr automatically populates this with the value of the top/parent ID. E.g. the profile ID. It is required. -->
    <field name="_root_" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false" docValues="false" />

    <!-- Is populated by Solr automatically with the path of the document in the hierarchy for non-root documents. -->
    <field name="_nest_path_" type="_nest_path_" />

    <!-- Is populated by Solr automatically to store the ID of each document’s parent document (if there is one). -->
    <field name="_nest_parent_" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

    <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />

    <!-- docValues are enabled by default for long type so we don't need to index the version field -->
    <field name="_version_" type="plong" indexed="false" stored="false" />
    
    <field name="_indexversion_" type="pint" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="false" required="true"
        default="4" />
        
    <field name="timestamp" type="pdate" indexed="true" stored="false" default="NOW" />
    <field name="content_type" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false" />

    <!-- define system values, which are known to be single valued -->
    <field name="creationdate_l" type="plong" indexed="true" stored="false" />
    <field name="lastmodifieddate_l" type="plong" indexed="true" stored="false" />
    <field name="firstvisit_l" type="plong" indexed="true" stored="false" />
    <field name="lastvisit_l" type="plong" indexed="true" stored="false" />

    <!-- behavioral properties -->
    <field name="frequency_bp" type="pint" indexed="true" stored="false" />
    <field name="intensity_bp" type="pint" indexed="true" stored="false" />
    <field name="recent_intensity_bp" type="pfloat" indexed="true" stored="false" />
    <field name="firstvisit_behavior_bp" type="pint" indexed="true" stored="false" />
    <field name="lastvisit_behavior_bp" type="pint" indexed="true" stored="false" />
    
    <!-- Profile meta data fields only have one value -->
    <field name="propertycount_i" type="pint" indexed="true" stored="false" />
    <field name="totalpropertycount_i" type="pint" indexed="true" stored="false" />
    <field name="totalpropertysize_i" type="pint" indexed="true" stored="false" />

    <field name="maxproperty_s" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false" />
    <field name="maxpropertyvalues_i" type="pint" indexed="true" stored="false" />

    <field name="system_has_property_s" type="strings" indexed="true" stored="false" />
    <field name="sample_id_i" type="pint" indexed="true" stored="false" />

    <field name="event_id" type="string" indexed="true" multiValued="false" stored="true" />
    <field name="event_type_id" type="string" indexed="true" multiValued="false" stored="true" />
    <field name="event_date" type="plong" indexed="true" multiValued="false" stored="true" />
    <field name="event_profile_id" type="string" indexed="true" multiValued="false" stored="true" />

    <dynamicField name="*_ordinal_i" type="pint" indexed="true" stored="false" />
    <dynamicField name="*_i" type="pints" indexed="true" stored="false" />
    <dynamicField name="*_l" type="plongs" indexed="true" stored="false" />
    <dynamicField name="*_f" type="pfloats" indexed="true" stored="false" />
    <dynamicField name="*_s" type="strings" indexed="true" stored="false" />
    <dynamicField name="*_b" type="boolean" indexed="true" stored="false" />

    <dynamicField name="momentum_bp_*" type="pint" indexed="true" stored="false" />
    <dynamicField name="threshold_*" type="plong" indexed="true" multiValued="false" stored="false" />
    <dynamicField name="firsttouch_*" type="plong" indexed="true" multiValued="false" stored="false" />
    <dynamicField name="reentryrestricted_*" type="string" indexed="true" multiValued="false" stored="false"/>
    <dynamicField name="exitentrancerestricted_*" type="string" indexed="true" multiValued="false" stored="false"/>
</schema>
```

Indexed documents:

```
{
        "id":"99c75c9a-b083-428d-baa1-6a9662c6eb72",
        "name_s":"Profile 1",
        "description_t":"test description",
        "age_is":[28,
          34],
        "creationdate_l":1658990989645,
        "content_type":"profile",
        "_version_":1739600934763233280,
        "_root_":"99c75c9a-b083-428d-baa1-6a9662c6eb72",
        "timeline_events":
        {
          "id":"dcde9bfd-97ee-4d76-97d8-5297c1b2e87d",
          "event_id":"order-0",
          "event_type_id":"order",
          "event_date":1658990989644,
          "total_revenue_f":865.0,
          "_nest_path_":"/timeline_events#",
          "_nest_parent_":"99c75c9a-b083-428d-baa1-6a9662c6eb72",
          "content_type":"timeline_event",
          "_version_":1739600934763233280,
          "_root_":"99c75c9a-b083-428d-baa1-6a9662c6eb72",
          "product":[
            {
              "id":"9dabaac8-7651-4c56-9fb4-66d56b7175c3",
              "name_s":"product-0",
              "promotion_s":"NO",
              "listprice_f":477.0,
              "quantity_i":22,
              "variant_ss":["handbags",
                "men"],
              "pages_i":1,
              "_nest_path_":"/timeline_events#/product#0",
              "_nest_parent_":"dcde9bfd-97ee-4d76-97d8-5297c1b2e87d",
              "content_type":"order_product",
              "_version_":1739600934763233280,
              "_root_":"99c75c9a-b083-428d-baa1-6a9662c6eb72"}]}},
      {
        "id":"c19483e2-f940-403f-bb24-03adce1bcb02",
        "name_s":"Profile 2",
        "description_t":"test description for profile 2",
        "age_is":[25,
          40],
        "creationdate_l":1658990989653,
        "content_type":"profile",
        "_version_":1739600934766379008,
        "_root_":"c19483e2-f940-403f-bb24-03adce1bcb02",
        "timeline_events":
        {
          "id":"dcde9bfd-97ee-4d76-97d8-5297c1b2e87d",
          "event_id":"order-4",
          "event_type_id":"order",
          "event_date":1658990989649,
          "total_revenue_f":952.0,
          "_nest_path_":"/timeline_events#",
          "_nest_parent_":"c19483e2-f940-403f-bb24-03adce1bcb02",
          "content_type":"timeline_event",
          "_version_":1739600934766379008,
          "_root_":"c19483e2-f940-403f-bb24-03adce1bcb02",
          "product":[
            {
              "id":"7a143554-b5f9-4487-b182-9938b91f76b4",
              "name_s":"product-4",
              "promotion_s":"YES",
              "listprice_f":487.0,
              "quantity_i":25,
              "variant_ss":["junior",
                "watches"],
              "pages_i":1,
              "_nest_path_":"/timeline_events#/product#0",
              "_nest_parent_":"dcde9bfd-97ee-4d76-97d8-5297c1b2e87d",
              "content_type":"order_product",
              "_version_":1739600934766379008,
              "_root_":"c19483e2-f940-403f-bb24-03adce1bcb02"}]}},
      {
        "id":"da88463c-fcca-4405-8656-0371809ccb28",
        "name_s":"Profile 3",
        "description_t":"test description for profile 3",
        "age_is":[34,
          39],
        "creationdate_l":1658990989648,
        "content_type":"profile",
        "_version_":1739600934768476160,
        "_root_":"da88463c-fcca-4405-8656-0371809ccb28",
        "timeline_events":
        {
          "id":"61f47b18-15f4-4a4d-bb93-a4232dd22043",
          "event_id":"order-2",
          "event_type_id":"order",
          "event_date":1658990989647,
          "total_revenue_f":838.0,
          "_nest_path_":"/timeline_events#",
          "_nest_parent_":"da88463c-fcca-4405-8656-0371809ccb28",
          "content_type":"timeline_event",
          "_version_":1739600934768476160,
          "_root_":"da88463c-fcca-4405-8656-0371809ccb28",
          "product":[
            {
              "id":"1fc4616b-2629-4cc4-8a60-7238f97c9aae",
              "name_s":"product-2",
              "promotion_s":"YES",
              "listprice_f":403.0,
              "quantity_i":26,
              "variant_ss":["pants",
                "women"],
              "pages_i":1,
              "_nest_path_":"/timeline_events#/product#0",
              "_nest_parent_":"61f47b18-15f4-4a4d-bb93-a4232dd22043",
              "content_type":"order_product",
              "_version_":1739600934768476160,
              "_root_":"da88463c-fcca-4405-8656-0371809ccb28"}]}}]
  }
}
```

When we execute the below query

```
{!parent which="*:* -_nest_path_:*"}event_id:order-0

OR

{!parent which="content_type:profile"}event_id:order-0
```

For this example, the queries do the same thing and both return the same incorrect result.

```
{
        "id":"da88463c-fcca-4405-8656-0371809ccb28",
        "name_s":"Profile 3",
        "description_t":"test description for profile 3",
        "age_is":[34,
          39],
        "creationdate_l":1658990989648,
        "content_type":"profile",
        "_version_":1739600934768476160,
        "_root_":"da88463c-fcca-4405-8656-0371809ccb28"
}
```

Which is not correct, the correct response would be

```
{
        "id":"99c75c9a-b083-428d-baa1-6a9662c6eb72",
        "name_s":"Profile 1",
        "description_t":"test description",
        "age_is":[28,
          34],
        "creationdate_l":1658990989645,
        "content_type":"profile",
        "_version_":1739600934763233280,
        "_root_":"99c75c9a-b083-428d-baa1-6a9662c6eb72"
}
```

Comment: Does the nested relationship of documents looks correct when using the [child] doc transformer ? You can check it by running the query `q=-_nest_path_:*&fl=*,[child]`. Could you update your post and put the (relevant part of the) output under "Indexed documents" (instead of the flat list), it would be more readable.

Comment: @EricLavault I updated the indexed document with children being included under the parents.

We identified what is causing the original issue (check answer below) and will look into what exactly is going wrong next week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more trial and error we discovered that the issue lies in

```
    <mergePolicyFactory class="org.apache.solr.index.SortingMergePolicyFactory">
      <str name="sort">id asc</str>
      <str name="wrapped.prefix">inner</str>
      <str name="inner.class">org.apache.solr.index.TieredMergePolicyFactory</str>
      <int name="inner.maxMergeAtOnce">10</int>
      <int name="inner.segmentsPerTier">10</int>
      <int name="inner.deletesPctAllowed">20</int>
    </mergePolicyFactory>
```

If this part is removed the results are correct.
We are still doing further investigation to identify what exactly is going wrong. Will keep updating the thread as we find more details.